# Custom Html heading sizes in boostrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am working on .NET 6 project that contains boostrap ver. 3. I am in process of upgrading to boostrap ver. 5. We are using the compiled version of boostrap 5 and then using our custom scss files to override default heading sizes.

```
body {
    font-family: #{$body-font-family};
    color: #{$Color-DarkPurple};

    p {
        font-size: 1.125rem; // 18 px
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 3rem; //48px;
        @include desktop {
            font-size: 3.375rem; //54px
        }
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 2.25rem; //36px;
        @include desktop {
            font-size: 3rem; //48px
        }
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 1.75rem; //28px;
        @include desktop {
            font-size: 2.25rem; //36px
        }
    }

    h4 {
        font-size: 0.75rem; //12px;
        @include desktop {
            font-size: 1.75rem; //28px
        }
    }

    h5 {
        font-size: 0.75rem; //12px;
    }
}
```

I can see that boostrap ver. 5.1.3 is using ->

```
h1,.h1 {
    font-size: calc(1.375rem + 1.5vw);
}
```

for screen size less than 1200px.

Am I missing something / bootstrap responsivness by not using **1.5vw**